# which one is loading faster SASS or SCSS or LESS

Tags: css

which one is faster? 
I will create the large web application. I will plan to use SCSS. But I have no idea which one is loading faster?

Comment: for sure CSS is faster since there is no compilating stuff but for the SCSS/LESS we should convert the file to a CSS valid one before send it. But don't forget that in some framework we have some cache and other features that can be good when using SCSS and LESS

Comment: Basically SCSS or LESS will compile down to CSS so I don't know if we could say that one is faster than the other... Maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think faster native CSS. But if you will pre-generate css from scss/less in server side - it will be same (i use this approach on my web project).

If you have plan generate css from scss/less on client side it will be one more operation